# UITableView detail

Tags: uitableview

I'm having an odd problem when I load my detail view from a UITable. It's almost as if the view seems to be loading on top of itself after the segue (to the detail) takes place. Has anyone seen this type of thing before, or have any ideas? It's been working fine for months, and now this happens.

The table view is fine

[image: :]

But when I click to go to detail view, I get this: the navigation bar is duplicated, one on top of the other, with the back button pushing itself onto only the bottom bar.

[image]

[image]

Comment: ur detail as also a navigationBar added.. through xib/code separately. Not the Bar comes from NavigationController

Comment: I'm not quite following you on that one. Could you clarify?

Comment: show me your detailView xib..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution at this link:

[Xcode 4 Navigation item prompt property misbehaving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419849/xcode-4-navigation-item-prompt-property-misbehaving)

the line of code that fixed this was simply:

```
    self.navigationItem.prompt = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

In detailViewController u have added a navigationItem by drag & drop, remove that. Because their is already a navigation bar exist from the root navigationController.

From your image i have pointed out that, just delete it.

[image]

Comment: I tried to delete that earlier, but using the delete key doesn't work.